# Undeclared Identifier Error in a simple program using structures for database

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

My compiler does not compile the following program I wrote. It gives an error at the lines I have marked stating that "Identifier not declared" even though I have declared it in my Main() function.

The program is incomplete, but it is going to take input about activity and output it.

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include <conio.h>


void addToLog();
void viewLog();

void what()
{
    cout << "What would you like to do?" << endl
         << "1. View Today's Log" << endl
         << "2. Add to Today's Log" << endl
         << "__________________________" << endl << endl
         << "? -> ";

    int in;

    cin  >> in;

    if ( in == 1 )
    {
        viewLog();
    }

    if ( in == 2 )
    {
        addToLog();
    }

}

void main()
{
    clrscr();


    struct database
    {
        char act[20];
        int time;
    };

    database db[24];



    what();



    getch();
}

void addToLog()
{
    int i=0;
    while (db[i].time == 0) i++;

    cout    << endl
        << "_______________________________"
        << "Enter Activity Name: ";
    cin     >> db[i].act;                           // <-------------
    cout    << "Enter Amount of time: ";
    cin >> db[i].time;
    cout    << "_______________________________";

    what();

}

void viewLog()
{
    int i=0;
    cout    << "_______________________________";
    for (i = 0; i <= 24; i++)
    {
        cout    << "1. " << db[i].act << "   " << db[i].time << endl; // <-------
    }
    cout    << "_______________________________";

    what();
}
```

Comment: @chris dude it is for a school project and I am forced not to use return types

Comment: Then a) It should be tagged as homework, and b) You should be asking your teacher why you have such a ridiculous restriction on `main`.

Comment: @chris - ill remember about the tag. BTW, my teacher recommends return types but she says it will be unfair to the others in my class since she wants us to use all the concepts of C++ and not only the advanced things.

Comment: It is an interesting approach by your teacher, but the C++ standard says main must return `int`. `void main()` doesn't even compile for me.

Comment: `void main()` is not part of C++, beginner or advanced. http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/bs_faq2.html#void-main

Comment: well, I did not know about that @chris . Thanks, I better tell my teacher about this, because I remember that she told us that we use int main() iff we want to use return types so that we save memory. It is also published in our computer science course books, amazing. It might be that it compiles since I am supposed to be using an archaic IDE called "Turbo C++".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have declared `db` as a local variable in `main()`; it cannot be seen by other functions.

There are at least two solutions:

1. Make `db` a global (static) variable - i.e. move its declaration/definition out of `main()`.  **This is generally not recommended, as it's usually poor practice to rely on global variables too much.**
2. Pass a pointer to `db` into functions that need it.

Comment: Is there no other way to do this except using pointers? I have to use this code for a Project and I am unable to use pointers etc. And I have not understood how to make it global. Do I just shift my structure outside main()?

Comment: @RohanVerma: Yes, move the definition of `database` and `db` outside of `main`.